# Rally C#: How to upload a collection of attachments and associate with a user story?

Tags: c#, api, rally

I have refereed to the other examples on this website, but found a major difference in my method. (Please be patient)

I am trying to iterate over a directory of files and upload each file as an attachment and associate to a user story.
I am only able to attach 1 file for a user story as of now.
I see that every attachment has to be encoded to a base 64 string and it must have a the size in bytes.

Here is my code so far:

```
 public void createUsWithAttachmentList(string workspace, string project, string userStoryName, string userStoryDescription)
    {

        //authentication
        this.EnsureRallyIsAuthenticated();

        //DynamicJSONObject for AttachmentContent
        DynamicJsonObject myAttachmentContent = new DynamicJsonObject();

        //Length calculated from Base64String converted back
        int imageNumberBytes = 0;

        //Userstory setup
        DynamicJsonObject toCreate = new DynamicJsonObject();
        toCreate["Workspace"] = workspace;
        toCreate["Project"] = project;
        toCreate["Name"] = userStoryName;
        toCreate["Description"] = userStoryDescription;

        //Trying to get a list of all the file paths within a given directory, this directory would contain .png files that need to be associated to a user story.
        string[] attachmentPath = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\RallyAttachments");
```

This foreach loop is confusing. I am trying to iterate over each file in the directory in order to convert it into a base64 string, and at the same time acquire the number of bytes for each file as an int.

```
        foreach (string fileName in attachmentPath)
        {
            Image myImage = Image.FromFile(fileName);
            string imageBase64String = imageToBase64(myImage, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            imageNumberBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageBase64String).Length;

            //I am stuck here to be exact because there are multiple imageBase64Strings due to the collection of files located inside the directory. AND the below line is wrong because I have a list of imageBase64Strings that were generated from iterating through the string[] attachmentPath.
            myAttachmentContent[RallyField.content] = imageBase64String;
        }

        try
        {
            //create user story
            CreateResult createUserStory = _api.Create(RallyField.attachmentContent, myAttachmentContent);
            //create attachment
            CreateResult myAttachmentContentCreateResult = _api.Create(RallyField.attachmentContent, myAttachmentContent);
            String myAttachmentContentRef = myAttachmentContentCreateResult.Reference;

            //DynamicJSONObject for Attachment Container
            //I assume I would need a separate container for each file in my directory containing the attachments.
            DynamicJsonObject myAttachment = new DynamicJsonObject();
            myAttachment["Artifact"] = createUserStory.Reference;
            myAttachment["Content"] = myAttachmentContentRef;
            myAttachment["Name"] = "AttachmentFromREST.png";
            myAttachment["Description"] = "Email Attachment";
            myAttachment["ContentType"] = "image/png"; 
            myAttachment["Size"] = imageNumberBytes;

            //create & associate the attachment
            CreateResult myAttachmentCreateResult = _api.Create(RallyField.attachment, myAttachment);
            Console.WriteLine("Created User Story: " + createUserStory.Reference);
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Note: I am planning on extending this method to support multiple file types, and I thing I would need to get the file type of each file in the directory and proceed accordingly. 
Any ideas on how to go about writing this?

Answer (score 1):

You've got all the parts implemented- we just need to move it around a little bit. Create the story once at the beginning, and then each time through the loop make a new AttachmentContent and a new Attachment for each file.

```
public void createUsWithAttachmentList(string workspace, string project, string userStoryName, string userStoryDescription)
{

    //authentication
    this.EnsureRallyIsAuthenticated();

    //Userstory setup
    DynamicJsonObject toCreate = new DynamicJsonObject();
    toCreate["Workspace"] = workspace;
    toCreate["Project"] = project;
    toCreate["Name"] = userStoryName;
    toCreate["Description"] = userStoryDescription;

    //Create the story first
    try
    {
        //create user story
        CreateResult createUserStory = _api.Create(RallyField.userStory, toCreate);


        //now loop over each file 
        string[] attachmentPath = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\RallyAttachments");

        foreach (string fileName in attachmentPath)
        {
            //DynamicJSONObject for AttachmentContent
            DynamicJsonObject myAttachmentContent = new DynamicJsonObject();
            Image myImage = Image.FromFile(fileName);
            string imageBase64String = imageToBase64(myImage, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            int imageNumberBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageBase64String).Length;
            myAttachmentContent[RallyField.content] = imageBase64String;

            //create the AttachmentConent
            CreateResult myAttachmentContentCreateResult = _api.Create(RallyField.attachmentContent, myAttachmentContent);
            String myAttachmentContentRef = myAttachmentContentCreateResult.Reference;

            //create an Attachment to associate to story
            DynamicJsonObject myAttachment = new DynamicJsonObject();
            myAttachment["Artifact"] = createUserStory.Reference;
            myAttachment["Content"] = myAttachmentContentRef;
            myAttachment["Name"] = "AttachmentFromREST.png";
            myAttachment["Description"] = "Email Attachment";
            myAttachment["ContentType"] = "image/png"; 
            myAttachment["Size"] = imageNumberBytes;

            //create & associate the attachment
            CreateResult myAttachmentCreateResult = _api.Create(RallyField.attachment, myAttachment);
        }     
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to push a zipped directory into Rally as an attachment. If so can you provide any pointers. I am starting to think that it has to be encoded int base 64 string.

Comment: A zip file is a valid attachment type.  You are correct- the content needs to be base4 encoded.